# How to handle size of toogling of Accordion?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I would like to create an accordion header with react bootstrap, like this, with only the title section toogler.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Title                                |   Button   |    
-----------------------------------------------------
```

The 'Title' section is only the one that make the toogling, I mean when I click in the Button section nothing happen (the accordion isn't toogled)

How can I do that ?

Comment: Why -1 ? Don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**react-bootstrap**
Visit https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/ just import the files required from react-bootstrap into your file and use it.
if you want to reduce button size than add col-6 or something to cardheader.if you want to reduce toggle card size than add col-6 or something to card-body.

Method1
use clear:both css for both "title" and "button" divs, I think the "Title" button is covering the "Button div

Method 2
Use zindex and also try to 'Button'